# How do I post a question about the etymology of an idiomatic expression?

Tags: discussion, etymology

I posted a question about the idiomatic expression "spit bath" and it was removed for "off topic."  Where and how can I pose this question on StackExchange?

Comment: If you are asking about an English expression, than it is probably better to ask in [English language and usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or in [English language learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), since it is a matter of specific language, not Linguistics (science about languages.)

Comment: see also some previous discussions on etymology questions across many previous years: https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/etymology-questions-and-close-votes
https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/the-need-for-changing-our-guidelines-for-etymology-questions
https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/good-examples-of-etymology-questions
https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143/which-etymology-questions-should-be-within-or-topic-scope

Answer (score 2):

One of the options available to users when voting to close a question is:

> Contextless Etymology Question
>
> Languages are always changing; words
> change their meanings and are borrowed between languages
> unpredictably. So questions asking for the **origin of words or phrases**
> are off-topic unless they demonstrate that there is a *reasonable*
> *assumption of systematicity*, by situating themselves within a
> historical context of language change or contact.

Your [question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46524/what-is-the-etymolgy-of-spit-bath) seems to meet that criterion for being off-topic.

For English words and phrases (like yours), these are generally considered on-topic on [the English Language & Usage site](https://english.stackexchange.com/), and for many other major languages there are also other suitable StackExchange sites. For etymologies in less often discussed languages there is unfortunately not always a suitable site on StackExchange.

Answer (score -3):

The real problem is that "idiomatic expressions" don't have etymologies.  **Words** have etymologies, because there is a small number of them, and their histories can often be traced historically.

But phrases and clauses are innumerable. Literally. And if they're not compositional (i.e, if their meaning isn't obviously clear from their parts), then they're much more likely to be metaphors, and that's what you should be looking for.

*Spit bath* is a good example. It's not a bath, and it needn't involve real spit, but it's an intended cleaning action, and liquid is involved. Both *spit* and *bath* are metaphoric terms, and so is their combination.

So its meaning can be explained by metaphor analysis (read Lakoff and Johnson); its history is lost, however. You can look in the OED to find the first **printed** use of *spit bath*, but that certainly is much later than its first actual use in speech. It won't have been written down (especially in a dictionary) until everybody understood what was meant, and that this phrase was not literal, but was meaningful. That could be centuries, especially for anything naughty like spit.

Comment: "spit bath" seems like a compound to me, albeit one spelt separately. Univerbation seems to also suggest that the line between compounds and phrases is not fixed, so I don't think this is a good argument

Comment: Phrases can still have etymologies, whether that's simply tracing their first uses, or whether they're calques from other languages etc.